# MVC 5 how to achieve POST that behaves like a redirect to GET with content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

My client redirects to a https://domain.com/Controller/GetInfo?Querystring method. Now my query string is getting dangerously close to the 2K limit, so I need to reproduce this behavior but pack my query string into the content of the messages. Since it would be heresy (etc.) to try a GET with content, I'll use a POST. However, I can't redirect to a POST since a Redirect has no content.

So, what I am looking for is the best MVC 5 pattern to resolve this: I need to provide lots of content, but I want the resulting page hosted on my remote server (i.e. as if I had redirected)

Also, since I use load balanced servers in azure, I'd prefer maintaining my clean stateless server if at all possible (else I'll have to introduce session caching).

Comment: I think this depends on the nature of the content to be passed - if there's a lot of it it is probably more appropriate to store it somewhere and just pass an identifier (especially if any of it is sensitive). I'd say a query string getting anywhere near 2k chars is almost definitely being abused.

Comment: I dont understand why you can just using jquery.Post and pass in your data.

Comment: Thanks. Non-JS clients  must be supported.

Answer (score 1):

@AntP is absolutely right in the comments above. If your query string is approaching 2K, then you're abusing it.

If there's a particular object you're referencing, then you can simply include the id or some other identifying piece of it and use that to look it up again from your data store.

If there's no persistent record of the object, then you can use something like `Session` or `TempData` to store it between one request and the next.

Regardless, it's not possible to redirect with a request body, with also means it's not possible to redirect using POST. The reason for this that the a redirect is not something the server does, but rather the client. The server merely suggests that the client go to a different URL. It's then up to the client (web browser) to issue a new request for that URL. Since the client is the one issuing the request, it makes the decision about what data is or isn't included in that request, not the server.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your server doesn't "want to store page state".

Comment: Thanks. I would like to maintain a stateless page server but would like to stop abusing query strings. Looks like I must resort to cached page-state or returning page content from the POST.